# How do I get the current frameid when displaying variables?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I implemented a lua debugger using the vscode extension. However, I encountered a problem while displaying variables.

The variables shown at the breakpoint are switched according to the stack frameid. When show variables, I need to get the correct frameid.

Switching to a certain stack level for the first time, I can get the stack frameid through the args of scopesRequest(), but when I switch to another stack level, the system will not give me a notify when switching back. because args of variablesRequest() have not current frameid, which will cause debugger use wrong stack level and get wrong variable.

eg.
Stack:

Function1   luafile:line 26     frameid = 0

Function2   luafile:line 30     frameid = 1

When I switch to function2, scopesRequest() will prompt me for frameid=1.
When I switch back to function1, I can't get a notification of the stack switch. At this time, expand UpValue, the variable read by debugger is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBExZ.png)

Comment: This might be the same issue I had/solved here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mock-debug/issues/82